# IME window overlap cursor in Edittext, how to prevent it?

Tags: android

I'm using Edittext and it has images and texts.
Then, I add image file on Edittext and I click Edittext, IME window shows, naturally.
( * At that time cursor is located at right-bottom corner of added image file.)
The problem is IME window overlap cursor, so users complain that 'where is my cursor?'

How to prevent that IME window overlap cursor?

Answer (score 0):

You could try "adjustResize" on your activity. In your AndroidManifest file

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"></activity>
```

There are other values for windowSoftInputMode that you could also try, e.g. "adjustPan".

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft